# get value from the dynamic create textbox

Tags: c#, dynamic

I am quite new in asp.net. I am wonder how can I get the value of the textbox that create dynamically from C#.

this code is the way i create the textbox from page load event...

```
for( int i =0; i<30; i++){                
                TextBox txt = new TextBox();
                txt.Text = "ASDASDASD";
                txt.ID = "txt - " + i.ToString(); 
                data.Controls.Add(txt);
    }
```

I wonder how can I get the value of the text box in button_click event. I tried string test = "txt - " + i.ToString(); but I unable to get it.

thanks for the help.

Comment: Why `i.ToString()` and not `txt.ToString()`?

Comment: what is i ? txt.Text should give you the value.

Comment: @Cyral coz I plan to do it in for loop. example like I have 30 textbox to create from code behind.

Comment: create textbox array and access it with i.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array or list of textboxes:

```
private TextBox[] textBoxes = new TextBox[30];
```

And assign a new textbox to each position:

```
for(int i =0; i<30; i++){                
      TextBox txt = new TextBox();
      txt.Text = "ASDASDASD";
      txt.ID = "txt - " + i.ToString(); 
      textBoxes[i] = txt;
      data.Controls.Add(txt);
}
```

To get the value of any textbox, do:

```
string value = textBoxes[i].Text;
```

Comment: but does the textboxed array can use it in another function? I mean within a cs file.

Comment: Put it outside of your function.

Comment: its throw me Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at the string value there.

Comment: Did you initialize the text boxes before?

Comment: I do what u have posted here and I add 


            string valuew = textBoxes[5].Text;
            TextBox2.Text = valuew;

to my button_Click. when I click then its throw me the error d

Comment: What value is null? When the error happens, hover over those variables and find which is null. (If using Visual Studio)

Comment: but I am using for loop to assign. all textbox are with value. yes, I am using visual studio

Comment: Did you miss the line `textBoxes[i] = txt;` in my loop? My code should work unless you didn't copy something here.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
String textvalue = String.Empty;
for(int i=0;i<= data.controls.count-1;i++)
{    
 //Specify the Index if u have 
  if(index == i)
     {
          Textbox txt = data.controls[i] as Textbox;
          textvalue  = txt.text;
          return;
     }
}
```

Comment: This is not a valid solution if the user adds any more controls than just those textboxes to the `data.controls` list. (Also, looping over all of the controls is not needed at all)